# Calculate time difference between two varchar2 columns which is having HH.MM format time

Tags: sql, oracle, time

I am trying to calculate the time difference between in and out time.

when using the below code it is giving wrong data.

```
(SELECT round(24 * (to_date(SIGN_OUT_TIME,'hh24:mi') - 
to_date(SIGN_IN_TIME,'hh24:mi')),2) diff_hours
FROM XXBCT.XXBCT_BIO_OTL_ENTRIES_SUMMARY
WHERE EMPLOYEE_NUMBER='112319'
AND attendance_dt    ='04-Jan-19');
```

The result should be 08.13 but it is giving 8.22

Comment: What happens if the times spans over midnight?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be really helpful.

Comment: 8 hours 13 minutes = 8.22 hours. The code is not wrong, the assumption of what the answer means appears to be wrong. Do you want the time difference in `HH24:MI` format or do you want the time difference in a fractional number of hours?

Answer (score 0):

8,22 are the difference in hours. 0.22 are not the minutes. That's the part of the whole hour. this corresponds to the expected 13 minutes.

Here is one way you can do it better.
You get the diffenrez in seconds
and then you can get the hours and minutes and seconds if you want

```
select TO_CHAR(TRUNC(diff_seconds/3600),'FM9900') || '.' ||
       TO_CHAR(TRUNC(MOD(diff_seconds,3600)/60),'FM00') || '.' ||
       TO_CHAR(MOD(diff_seconds,60),'FM00')
  from (SELECT round(24 * 60 * 60 (to_date(SIGN_OUT_TIME,'hh24:mi') 
                                 - to_date(SIGN_IN_TIME,'hh24:mi')),2) diff_seconds
          FROM XXBCT.XXBCT_BIO_OTL_ENTRIES_SUMMARY
          WHERE EMPLOYEE_NUMBER='112319'
          AND attendance_dt    ='04-Jan-19'
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

For a time difference, Oracle has a data type, it is called `interval`:

http://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-interval/

> Oracle provides you with two date time data types: DATE and TIMESTAMP for storing point-in-time data. In addition, It provides the INTERVAL data type that allows you to store periods of time.

For me, this is the way I prefer to work with time differences, as it saves all the crumbersome computation otherwise required when working with dates only. The 'trick' in the below query is that I convert one date to a timestamp via `to_timestamp`. A `timestamp` minus a `date` gives you an `interval` in return:

```
with 
first_date_vc2   as (select                '01:00' val from dual),
second_date_vc2  as (select                '09:13' val from dual),
first_date_date  as (select to_date(val,'HH24:MI') val from first_date_vc2),
second_date_date as (select to_date(val,'HH24:MI') val from second_date_vc2)
select 
    to_timestamp(sdd.val)-fdd.val 
from first_date_date fdd,second_date_date sdd;

-- TO_TIMESTAMP(SDD.VAL)-FDD.VAL
-- +00 08:13:00.000000
```

Including your desired output formatting:

```
with 
first_date_vc2   as (select                '01:00'        val from dual),
second_date_vc2  as (select                '09:13'        val from dual),
first_date_date  as (select to_date(val,'HH24:MI')        val from first_date_vc2),
second_date_date as (select to_date(val,'HH24:MI')        val from second_date_vc2),
interval_between as (select to_timestamp(sdd.val)-fdd.val val from first_date_date fdd,second_date_date sdd)
select 
    extract( hour from val)||':'||extract( minute from val) val
from interval_between;

-- VAL
-- 8:13
```

As a commenter already pointed out, the actual query needed will vary with requirements, such as whether it can be more than 24 hours or whether it can run over midnight.

Answer (score 0):

8 hours 13 minutes = 8.22 hours

If you just want the a number with the units part as the hours and the fractional part as the minutes then you can take the fractional part of your answer and multiply it by `0.6`:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE XXBCT_BIO_OTL_ENTRIES_SUMMARY (
  EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, ATTENDANCE_DT, SIGN_IN_TIME, SIGN_OUT_TIME
)
AS
SELECT '112319',
       DATE '2019-01-04',
       TO_CHAR( TIMESTAMP '2019-01-04 00:00:00', 'HH24:MI' ),
       TO_CHAR( TIMESTAMP '2019-01-04 08:13:00', 'HH24:MI' )
FROM   DUAL
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT ROUND( diff_hours, 2 ) AS diff_hours,
       TRUNC( diff_hours ) + MOD( diff_hours, 1 ) * 0.60 AS diff_hours_hhmi
FROM   (
  SELECT 24 * (to_date(SIGN_OUT_TIME,'hh24:mi') - to_date(SIGN_IN_TIME,'hh24:mi'))
           AS diff_hours
  FROM   XXBCT_BIO_OTL_ENTRIES_SUMMARY
  WHERE  EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = '112319'
  AND    attendance_dt   = DATE '2019-01-04'
);
```

**Output**:

```
DIFF_HOURS | DIFF_HOURS_HHMI
---------: | --------------:
      8.22 |            8.13
```

You could also use an `INTERVAL` data type:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(SIGN_OUT_TIME,'hh24:mi') - TO_TIMESTAMP(SIGN_IN_TIME,'hh24:mi') AS diff_hours_interval,
       SUBSTR(TO_TIMESTAMP(SIGN_OUT_TIME,'hh24:mi') - TO_TIMESTAMP(SIGN_IN_TIME,'hh24:mi'), 12, 5 ) AS diff_hours_interval_string
FROM   XXBCT_BIO_OTL_ENTRIES_SUMMARY
WHERE  EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = '112319'
AND    attendance_dt   = DATE '2019-01-04';
```

```
DIFF_HOURS_INTERVAL           | DIFF_HOURS_INTERVAL_STRING
:---------------------------- | :-------------------------
+000000000 08:13:00.000000000 | 08:13
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d33e28a8fb113ffa2459af120fef69ff)*